# Django REST FileUpload Parser does not work with images

Tags: python, django, django-rest-framework

I am very new to Django. I am trying to develeop a web service using REST Framework. The client will send me image or pdf and I will do some image processing on this files. When i send a multipart/formdata request from Postman with attachment, pdf files are saved correctly, but images are not.

**views.py**

```
class FileUploadView(APIView):

parser_classes = (FileUploadParser,)

def post(self, request, format="file"):
    file_obj = request.FILES['file']
    #file_name = default_storage.save(file_obj.name, file_obj)
    filename = 'filename'
    with open(filename, 'wb+') as temp_file:
        for chunk in file_obj.chunks():
            temp_file.write(chunk)

    return Response(file_obj.name, status.HTTP_201_CREATED)
```

Can you help me? What am i doing wrong?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You just need to change parser to Multipart parser :)

```
parser_classes = (MultiPartParser,FileUploadParser,)
```

Comment: When answering your own question, consider including updated code so that future users understand what you did to solve your problem.